# Configuring off-heap memory mode

Tags: java, ignite

I'm using ignite 2.0 and since no `setMemoryMode` method is available anymore I cannot set it explicitly. But when I tried to load caches I noticed in ignitevisor:

```
Entries(Heap / Off-heap)
min 223(223/0)
avg 223 (223/0)
max 223(223/0)
```

It means all cache are on-heap. How to configure it in ignite 2.0?

This `CacheConfiguration::setOnheapCacheEnabled(false);` didnt work

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.0 with default configuration Ignite stores entries in off-heap.
It's a problem with visor, here is a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5461).

You can check that your entries placed in off-heap by using

```
cache.size(CachePeekMode.OFFHEAP)
```